# why sed is replacing all the words without g command on kali linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I didn't use the command 's/I/You/g' then why does it changes the I into you in the second line?

I run the code

```
$ sed 's/I/You/' <oldfile >newfile
$ cat newfile
You am Likith
You am Likith
```

And it should print
"You am Likith
I am Likith"

Any idea?

Comment: There is this helpful command `man <command>` that shows you a nicely formatted documentation of `<command>` (except on really stripped down server setups where the man pages are not installed in order to save space). If you do `man sed` and read the description section, you'll figure it out that the commands (`s/I/You/` in your case) are run on each line of the input.

Answer (score 3):

The `g` flag replaces all the occurrences in a single line. In your case you have only one **I** occurence for each line.

You source file has many lines, each one with a one occurence, and as you should know **sed** apply the same rule to each of them.

Try what I am telling you simply by adding a second `I` instance on a line of them: you should got replaced only the first one.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -z 's/I/You/' file
```

Using the `-z` command option will (most likely) treat the entire file as a single line and thus only the first match will be substituted.

See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options) for documentation.

Comment: Wouldn't this mangle newlines if you redirect the output to a file (with -i or a temp file ) ?

Comment: @Aserre no, it treats newlines as just another character. Perhaps I should have phrased it as "it treats the entire file as just one string".